# Displaying text on dialog box

Tags: winapi, modal-dialog

How to display text on dialog-box? for example - I want to display a countdown timer, should I go with static text control?

Comment: Yes, that's what it is made for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a static text control and then call the function

```
BOOL SetWindowText(      
    HWND hWnd,
    LPCTSTR lpString
);
```

to set the text at runtime.

See [online Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633546%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I thought SetWindowText() API was only to set the window's title caption.